# Marsaglia bray, converting VBA code to Python

Tags: python, vba, excel

I was wondering if someone knows how to convert this VBA code for a random variable generation into Python.
(The "Saved" variable is a Boolean in VBA)

```
function MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd() As Double
Dim U1 As Double, U2 As Double
Dim x As Double, Y As Double

If Saved = False Then
   x = 2

   While x > 1
      U1 = (2 * Rnd() - 1)
      U2 = (2 * Rnd() - 1)
      x = (U1 * U1) + (U2 * U2)
   Wend

   Y = Sqr(-2 * Log(x) / x)
   MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd = U1 * Y
   SavedNormSRnd = U2 * Y
   Saved = True
Else
   MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd = SavedNormSRnd
   Saved = False
End If

End Function
```

I tried this code myself but did not get it to work:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd(u1,u1,x,y):
if Saved==False:
    x = 2

    while x > 1:
        np.random.seed(1)
        u1 = 2 * np.random.random((3,1)) - 1
        u2 = 2 * np.random.random((3,1)) - 1
        x = (u1 * u1) + (u2 * u2)   

    y = math.sqrt(-2 * math.log(x) / x)
    MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd = u1 * y
    SavedNormSRnd = u2 * y
    Saved = True
else:
    MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd = SavedNormSRnd
    Saved = False
```

Comment: correct indentation, what isn't working

Comment: VBA: `If Saved = False Then`, python `if Saved==True:`. Are you for real?

Comment: indentation NOT correct -- see def followed by if at same indent level

Comment: Saved and SaveNormSRnd need to be either globals (YUK!) or args that must be carried around or attributes of a class instance

Comment: need to return some value, don't assign to function name

Comment: np is not defined

Comment: I don't know python (I came to the question because of the vba tag) but should `def MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd(u1,u1,x,y):` be `def MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd(u1,u2,x,y):` ?

Answer (score 1):

No need for the truly hideous constructions required in many other languages!

```
from random import random
from numpy import sqrt, log

def MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd():
    while True:
        x = 2
        while x > 1:
            u1 = 2 * random() - 1
            u2 = 2 * random() - 1
            x = (u1 * u1) + (u2 * u2)   
        y = sqrt( -2 * log(x) / x )
        yield u1 * y
        yield u2 * y

for i, N in enumerate(MarsagliaBrayNormSRnd()):
    print (N)
    if i>10:
        break
```